# After being recruited, when can you change jobs?

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, quitting, internal-transfer

In terms of etiquette, how long after being recruited to a position, should one wait before seeking to transfer to a new department or leave the company entirely?

*To clarify my question:* In general, should the expected worklife be different for employees that are recruited vs those that are not?

There is of course a lot of added cost required to pay a recruiter to find the right employee. So where I would hope that my non-recruited employees stick around for at least a year (hopefully 2+), Should employers generally expect anything different from recruited employees?

Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Without more details, it is extremely difficult to answer. What are the conditions? What are the warning signs, if any, that you see telling you that you should move to a different department or company? What does your gut tell you? How good or bad is it where you are now?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the company and its culture.  First step would be to speak with some of your coworkers.  Even if there is no set policy, im sure there has been office gossip.  "Oh yea Bob asked for a transfer after being here for 6 months and they didnt let him move to another department for another 3 years".

But that being said, it is your career, and sometimes you need to make a change that is best for your mental health or wallet health without concern for the companies bottom line.